# ckeditor scrollIntoView to a div element within the editor

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor

I have a navigation menu out side ckeditor and i want to navigate within the editor as all my element in editor have ids

scrollIntoView

how does this work

any example will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844569/ckeditor-class-or-id-for-editor-body) (asked by myself some months ago) should get you started. 
The accepted answer outlines how to access elements inside the CKEditor document programmatically from JQUery.

It should be possible to fetch the desired element, and do a `ScrollIntoView` based on that.

This *might* already work (untested):

```
var documentWrapper = editorname.document; // replace by your CKEDitor instance ID
var documentNode = documentWrapper.$; // or documentWrapper['$'] ;
documentNode.getElementById("id").scrollIntoView(); // Insert your element ID there
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Where are you stuck? What error messages come up?

Comment: documentNode.getElementById("e_data") is null

e_data is within the iframe of the editor and i am calling it from parent script

Comment: CKEDITOR.document.getById("e_data") is null

still no luck

Comment: Can focus() be used in any to assist in this problem or show().

Comment: Are you 100% sure your editor instance is name CKEDITOR? What happens if you use the code in my answer, remove the last line, open a Firebug console and say `console.log(documentNode);`? Can you post the line with which you initialize the CKeditor?

Comment: Regarding focus() or show(): No, you need to get hold of the element first

Comment: ReferenceError: documentNode is not defined { message="documentNode is not defined",  more...}

Comment: works fine for CKEDITOR

console.log(CKEDITOR);
Object { timestamp="99GE", more...}

Comment: The console.log needs to be after when you create `documentNode` in the example above. And re CKEDITOR, that is *not necessarily* your *editor instance*. You need to access the variable name of your *editor instance*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not actually putting the scope inside the CKEDITOR instance.
In order to get a variable pointing to the document, do this:

```
var ckeditorDocument = CKEDITOR.instances.[instancename].document.$;
```