# CKEditor dialog select box dynamic population

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have two select boxes in a dialog..I was wondering if i can set the contents of the second select box based on the selection of the first box..i.e if select box1 has x selected, then select box2 contents are a, b, c..if select box1 has y selected, then select box2 contents are d, e, f.. Is this possible to implement?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing that the dialog with two select boxes you mentioned is part of a custom plugin you are creating. So my answer shows code you could use in the dialog file that's being created as part of the plugin.

The onChange function of Selector One creates a reference to Selector Two using:

```
dialog.getContentElement( 'general', 'selectorTwo' )
```

'general' is the id of the dialog panel containing the selectors.
'selectorTwo' is the id of the second selector.

I modified the source code from the SimpleLink tutorial hosted at cksource.com:
**Creating a CKEditor Plugin with a Custom Dialog Window**
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/SimpleLink_Plugin_Part_1

Download the SimpleLink source code here:
http://docs.cksource.com/images/a/a8/SimpleLink.zip

Unzip and add the simpleLink folder to your ckeditor/plugins directory.

Update your config file by adding the simpleLink plugin to your extraplugins list:
config.extraPlugins = 'onchange,insertsnippet,resconfinearea,resiframe,simpleLink',

Or when you do CKEDITOR.replace use:
extraPlugins : 'onchange,insertsnippet,resconfinearea,resiframe,simpleLink',

Also add the button to your toolbar - 'SimpleLink'

You're going to insert the code snippet from the bottom of this message into the ckeditor/plugins/simpleLink/plugin.js file.

To make the insertion point easy to locate, the first twelve lines of the snippet overlap with lines ( 111 - 122 ) of the simpleLink/plugin.js file.

After you insert the snippet, open ckeditor/_source/plugins/forms/dialogs/select.js.
Copy the following three functions from the top of the select.js file and add them at the top of the simpleLink/plugin.js file:
**addOption**()
**removeAllOptions**()
**getSelect**()

---

Open a page that's using CKEditor and click on the SimpleLink button you added, you'll see selectors one and two at the bottom of the dialog window. When you change selector one, selector two will be updated. You should be able to modify the code to suit your application.

These pages have some useful information you can refer to when reviewing the code I posted:

**Creating a CKEditor Plugin with a Custom Dialog Window**
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/SimpleLink_Plugin_Part_1

**Class CKEDITOR.dialog**
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html

**Class CKEDITOR.dialog.definition**
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.html

Here's the code snippet to insert into the ckeditor/plugins/simpleLink/plugin.js file.
Just select lines ( 111 - 122 ) and paste this in:

```
{
  type : 'checkbox',
  id : 'newPage',
  label : 'Opens in a new page',
  // Default value.
  // http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.checkbox.html#constructor
  'default' : true,
  commit : function( data )
  {
    data.newPage = this.getValue();
  }
},
{
  type : 'select',
  id : 'selectorOne',
  label : 'Selector One',
  items :
  [
    [ '<none>', '' ],
    [ 'Set 1', 1],
    [ 'Set 2', 2 ],
    [ 'Set 3', 3 ]
  ],
  onChange : function()
  {
    var dialog = this.getDialog(),
      values = dialog.getContentElement( 'general', 'selectorTwo' ), // 'general' is the id of the dialog panel.
      selectedSet = parseInt(this.getValue());

    switch(selectedSet)
    {
    case 1:
      optionsNames = new Array("Set One <none>","Set One A","Set One B","Set One C"),
      optionsValues = new Array("","setOneA","setOneB","setOneC");
      break;
    case 2:
      optionsNames = new Array("Set Two <none>","Set Two A","Set Two B","Set Two C"),
      optionsValues = new Array("","setTwoA","setTwoB","setTwoC");
      break;
    case 3:
      optionsNames = new Array("Set Three <none>","Set Three A","Set Three B","Set Three C"),
      optionsValues = new Array("","setThreeA","setThreeB","setThreeC");
      break;
    default:
      optionsNames = new Array("<none>"),
      optionsValues = new Array("");
    }

    removeAllOptions( values );

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < optionsNames.length ; i++ )
    {
      var oOption = addOption( values, optionsNames[ i ],
        optionsValues[ i ], dialog.getParentEditor().document );
      if ( i == 0 )
      {
        oOption.setAttribute( 'selected', 'selected' );
        oOption.selected = true;
      }
    }
  },
  commit : function( data )
  {
    data.selectorOne = this.getValue();
  }
},
{
  type : 'select',
  id : 'selectorTwo',
  label : 'Selector Two',
  items :
  [
    [ '<none>', '' ]
  ],
  commit : function( data )
  {
    data.selectorTwo = this.getValue();
  }
},
```

Hope this does the trick, let me know if something isn't clear,
Joe

---

Hi oggiemc,

Good to know that you've had a chance to experiment with the code and it's great that it's been helpful.

Answers to the additional questions about the functions copied from the plugins/forms/dialogs/select.js file.

1) The three functions shouldn't be called when the dialog is opened. That's not occurring in the sample I created as outlined in my initial answer. You might want to search your code for the three function names to see if they are being called someplace other than the ( onChange : function() ) contained in the selectorOne definition.

2) I broke down the ( removeAllOptions() function ) and included it below. It has a similar line of code. For the line you asked about:

```
if (combo && oOption && oOption.getName() == 'option'),
```

It says If ( combo exists ) AND ( oOption exists ) AND ( oOption.getName() == 'option' ) the If statement is true.
By "exists", I mean it's not null and not something that evaluates to false (either 0 or a binary Not true).

3) Yes, in this particular usage of the addOption() function, the index variable isn't used. You can remove the two if statements and just leave the code statement from each else clause.

4) obj.getInputElement() returns the DOM element object, but obj.getInputElement().$ only returns the HTML tag for the DOM object. Try adding some console.log calls to the getSelect() function and you'll see the difference:

```
if ( obj && obj.domId && obj.getInputElement().$ ) {        // Dialog element.
  console.log(obj.getInputElement().$); // ADDED CONSOLE.LOG
  console.log(obj.getInputElement()); // ADDED CONSOLE.LOG
```

### return  obj.getInputElement();

Here is the flow for the removeAllOptions() function:
In the onChange() function for selectorOne we create a variable "values" which represents selectorTwo.
values = dialog.getContentElement( 'general', 'selectorTwo' )

Before populating selectorTwo with new option values based on the option selected in selectorOne, we remove any existing options from selectorTwo:
removeAllOptions( values ); // values represents selectorTwo

Within the removeAllOptions() function the variable "combo" is assigned the value that was passed in the function call, so:
combo = values = selectorTwo.

The removeAllOptions() function calls the getSelect() function and sends it the "combo" variable as a parameter.
The "combo" variable will be assigned the value that is returned by the getSelect() function.

Within the getSelect() function the variable "obj" is assigned the value that was passed in the function call, so:
obj = combo = values = selectorTwo.

The getSelect() function can return one of three values:
A) if ( obj && obj.domId && obj.getInputElement().$ )
If obj is true AND if obj.domId is true AND if obj.getInputElement().$ returns anything other than false or null, it will return the value of obj.getInputElement().
So, if the obj variable exists and the domId property of obj is set, it will run the getInputElement() function on obj and check that the DOM property ($) is set.
getInputElement() uses the domId to return the DOM element that corresponds to the selectorTwo element.

B) If not all three parts of A were true, the getSelect() function tries:
if ( obj && obj.$ )
So, if the obj variable exists and it already is the DOM element ($), it will just send back obj.

C) If step B fails, then getSelect() returns false and selectorTwo doesn't have any option elements to remove.

Now back to the removeAllOptions() function to see what happens if step A or B of getSelect() returns something.
In both cases the "combo" variable will be the selectorTwo object with the DOM element (combo.$) set.
It runs a while loop over the array of option elements inside selectorTwo and removes them.
It gets the first option element "getChild( 0 )" and removes it, the option element that was at position Child( 1 ) moves to position Child( 0 ) and the loop continues until there are no option elements left.

The getInputElement() function is located at line ( 1085 ) of ckeditor_source\plugins\dialogui\plugin.js
The getInputElement() function calls the getElement() function.
The getElement() function is located at line ( 2560 ) of ckeditor_source\plugins\dialog\plugin.js

```
function removeAllOptions( combo )
{
  combo = getSelect( combo );
  while ( combo.getChild( 0 ) && combo.getChild( 0 ).remove() )
  { /*jsl:pass*/ }
}

function getSelect( obj )
{
  if ( obj && obj.domId && obj.getInputElement().$ )        // Dialog element.
    return  obj.getInputElement();
  else if ( obj && obj.$ )
    return obj;
  return false;
}
```

Be Well,
Joe

Comment: Hi joe, Many thanks for your help..Where exactly do i paste in the 3 select functions though?? I pasted them in the plugin section but got an error..Do they go in the dialog section? Thanks again

Comment: Hi Joe, got it working now..Put it in the dialog section of the code..Im gona start testing now..Will let you know how i get on..Thanks again

Comment: Hi joe, Have got this working now thanks alot..I have a question though, if i wanted another select box to be updated the same way as selector two would this take much modification to the code? Also, i was wondering could you perhaps give a commented version of the 3 functions : addOption(), removeAllOptions(), getSelect()..Because i cant really see how this code updates selectorTwo? I can open these up as a new question if you like..

Comment: Hi oggiemc, I started working with CKEditor a few weeks ago. I've looked at the questions you've posted as an opportunity to teach myself about how the editor works. I didn't know the answer to any of your four questions that I've answered when I first read them. In this case, I took the SimpleLink Plugin Tutorial and experimented by making changes to get an understanding of how it worked. I've spent hours looking through the API to find the methods needed to create the code for the four questions I've answered.

Comment: My hope is that you're taking the code I provided and spending some time experimenting with it to gain an understanding of how it works. Have you tried to add another select box? Please ask some specific questions that show you are making an effort to learn.

Comment: Hi Joe, i understand your concern but i just want to say I am experimenting with the code you send me and im not just looking for answers..I have added another selector to my code (selector3) and have defined an empty items array.. I understand the code you posted above, but i dont really understand the 3 functions from the select plugin..More specifically : (1) These functions seem to execute straight away as soon as the dialog button is clicked..I put a breakpoint in the addOption function and the 3 functions begin executing when the dialog button is clicked.. Should they not only be

Comment: executed when the onChange event is fired on selectorOne?? (2) From addOption : if (combo && oOption && oOption.getName() == 'option'), this evaluates as true yet the value of combo in firebug is object?? (3) Since index is not passed as an argument to addOption, there isnt really any need for code in addOption that contains the word index? (4) In getSelect(), what is the difference between obj.getInputElement() and obj.getInputElement().$. Thanks

Comment: Hi joe, I figured out how to set up selector3..Was straightforward when i realised what to do..Think i have a better grasp of whats going on in the select functions now, but the questions above still remain..

Comment: Hi oggiemc, I added my response to the four questions about the functions to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its totally possible to implement.. In the code, put 2 select boxes.
Then in the js code of that plugin, bind a clickhandler to the select box which puts the value u want in the second select box.

Comment: Thanks Ghostrider, But how do i get a reference to the dialog select box from within the plugin code?

Comment: in the plugin code, use jquery to get the reference and value of the selectbox.

Comment: Hi Ghostcoder, ive never used jquery before..Can you elaborate a bit or perhaps give me an example? I really dont know what to do..Thanks

Comment: no need to use jquery.
just put event listeners on the selectboxes, when one is selected, the  function in the event listener can set the value of the second checkbox.

Comment: hi ghostrider, i understand what you are asking to do from your first post..The problem i have is dont know how to get a reference to the dialog select box i.e in my plugin code, how do i reference the select box??The select box is defined by an items property, how do i reference that property in the plugin code??