# how to change a loaded stylesheet after initialisation of ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to dynamically change the loaded stylesheet for a ckeditor instance?

i.e. i have a ckeditor instance with the following config:
CKEDITOR.replace('_content', {"resize_enabled":true, "customConfig":"/kmt/js/ckeditor_config.js","contentsCss":"/custom/ckeditorstyle.css","contentWidth":"240"});

Not very complicated. Afterwards i want to allow the user to dynamically change the contentscss attribute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine the code given in the answer to [**this SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126238/load-external-stylesheets-on-request) (How to dynamically add style sheets during runtime) with the accepted [**answer to this SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844569/ckeditor-class-or-id-for-editor-body) (How to access the `body` element of a CKEditor instance in JavaScript).

Answer (score 3):

Thanx to Pekka, I achieved the solution via:

```
$('#stylesheeetSelector').change(function() {
    $.post('/getStylesheet', {id: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
        for(i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            var linkElement = $(CKEDITOR.instances[i].document.$).find('link');
            if (data.editorStylesheet > 0) {
                if (linkElement.length == 0) {
                    $(CKEDITOR.instances[i].document.$).find('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+ data.editorStylesheet +'">');
                } else {
                    linkElement.attr('href', data.editorStylesheet)
                }
            } else if (linkElement.length > 0) {
                linkElement.remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It works by fetching a JSON object filled with (amoungst other things) the stylesheet URL and sets (or removes if none present) the selected stylesheet...

Clean and simple!